# python numpy array data manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 csv files with 16 columns and 146 rows.
I am trying to do the following (*This is not actual data*):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
final output of the script intended:
x = [ 11, 22, 33, 22, 22.5, 33] # basically the last half of the array needs to be divided by 2
```

I have tried out the follwoing code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import sys    
data = np.genfromtxt('./test1.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
data_sys = np.genfromtxt('.test2.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
z = np.add (data, data_sys)
np.savetxt("new_before_avg.csv", z, delimiter= ',')

z[:,8:15] = z[:,8:15]/2

np.savetxt("new_after_avg.csv"], z, delimiter= ",")
```

Problem is, I am seeing the final output as expected except for the last column (*column 15*). It is just added up, did not divide by 2.

I thought my indexing was right. Please help.

Comment: if there are 16 columns why do you slice 8:15? Remember python slices go up the index before the end! i.e 8:16 -> 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z[:,8:15]` indexes *up to but not including* the last column (the 16th, indexed at `z[:,15]`).

Use `z[:, 8:]` or `z[:,8:16]`